# failed to connect to the existing server farm in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, server-farm

Sharepoint 2013 was uninstallted from the Virtual Machine which is Windows 2012 R2. Installed the Sharepoint [image]software again. When running the configuration wizard again, trying to connect to the existing server farm. However I am getting error as shown in the image

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling SharePoint 2013 dismounts SharePoint databases from its web applications, physical file still stored in the database server, however the old farm no longer exists.

It's necessary to create a new farm instead of joining old farm.